# Custom Action CommandUIDefinition Location for Calendar All Events and Current Events Views

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, calendar, custom-actions

I am trying to  create a custom Action for Ribbon Menu for calendar list for SharePoint using CSOM. I am able to create custom action for the calendar  view Successfully  with the **below code**, I am trying to implement the same for the All Events view and Current Events and changed the **Location** attribute for the **CommandUIDefinition** tag with different values as mentioned in the Msdn link [Customization Locations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537543(v=office.14).aspx)

```
                   var SourceList = destinationContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(Listnameitem);
                    destinationContext.Load(SourceList);
                    destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserCustomActionCollection collUserCustomAction = SourceList.UserCustomActions;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserCustomAction RemoveRibbonaction = collUserCustomAction.Add();
                    RemoveRibbonaction.Location = "CommandUI.Ribbon.ListView";
                    RemoveRibbonaction.Sequence = 10002;
                    RemoveRibbonaction.Title = "RemoveDocuments";
                    location = "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.Calendar.Events.Share.Controls._children\">";
                    //location = "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.Items.Actions.Share._children\">";
                    //location = "<CommandUIDefinition Location=\"Ribbon.ListItem.Share._children\">";
                    string RemoveDocumentRibbonActionurl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
                    RemoveRibbonaction.CommandUIExtension = @"<CommandUIExtension><CommandUIDefinitions>"
                    + location
                    + "<Button Id=\"InvokeAction.Button1\" TemplateAlias=\"o1\" Command=\"EditFormButtonCommand1\" CommandType=\"General\" LabelText=\"RemoveDocuments\" Image32by32=\"_layouts/15/images/placeholder32x32.png\" Image16by16=\"_layouts/15/images/placeholder16x16.png\" />"
                    + "</CommandUIDefinition>"
                    + "</CommandUIDefinitions>"
                    + "<CommandUIHandlers>"
                    + "<CommandUIHandler Command =\"EditFormButtonCommand1\" CommandAction = \"javascript:OpenPopUpPageWithTitle('" + RemoveDocumentRibbonActionurl + "', RefreshOnDialogClose, 600, 400,'Remove Documents');\"  EnabledScript=\"javascript: SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems().length >= 1\" /> "
                    + "</CommandUIHandlers></CommandUIExtension>";
                    RemoveRibbonaction.Update();
                    destinationContext.Load(SourceList, list => list.UserCustomActions);
                    destinationContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I Would like to know the value for the location attribute   for The  All Events view and Current Events View. I tried with **Ribbon.Items.Actions.Share._children** and **Ribbon.Items.Actions.Share._children** values but unable to create custom action in the mentioned views

Can anyone help me on this.